# Jumping to end/beginning of line in "less -S"

Tags: less, pager

The commonly used pager `less` can be started with the option `-S`, prevents it from breaking lines.

One can then press the right and left arrow keys to scroll horizontally.

Since the lines can be quite long, I was wondering whether there a keystroke or a way to jump to the end of the line.

I know that one can increase the step size `less` uses for scrolling.
The problem is, that `less` doesn't stop to scroll horizontally at the end of the line.
Therefore just setting a high numerical value for the step size (scrolling increment) would usually put the view beyond the end of the line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the manual:

```
   ESC-} or ^RIGHTARROW
          Scroll horizontally right to show the end of the longest displayed line.

   ESC-{ or ^LEFTARROW
          Scroll horizontally left back to the first column.
```

These escape sequences were introduced in [`less` version 487, released on 2016-10-25](http://greenwoodsoftware.com/less/news.487.html).

Comment: Seems like this is a new feature. For Ubuntu, it's only available starting from 18.04.

Comment: The version of Ubuntu is not as important as the version of `less`.

Comment: `less -V` yields `less 487 (POSIX regular expressions)` for me.